# Create new worksheet using VBA macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create worksheets depending on the number of files present in the current folder.This is my current folder:

```
Folder
      CalculationSheet.xls
      Data1.xls
      Data2.xls
      Data3.xls
```

So I'll be searching for "`/*.xls`" using the count.
I need to create worksheets in `CalculationSheet.xls` as I am new to macro. Please help me on this.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, please add more information or if it's possible some sample or code.

Comment: Hi sha, Say for example i have a folder which has the following excel files.

Folder
      CalculationSheet.xls
      Data1.xls
      Data2.xls

So now i need a button(macro) in CalculationSheet.xls which when pressed should count number of Data*.xls files in current folder and should create that many number of worksheet in my CalculationSheet.xls with sheet name as filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use a code something like this:

```
Sub GetDataFiles()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fileTemp As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Open library of Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    If (fso.FolderExists(strFolder)) Then

        ' Check All files in the folder
        For Each fileTemp In fso.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
            If fileTemp.Name Like "Data*.xls" Then
                Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
                ws.Name = fileTemp.Name
            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```